# CSS: Overflow clipping while scrolling

Tags: css, firefox, scroll, overflow, clipping

I have a CSS problem in Firefox. I'm not 100% if it is a Firefox bug or is there a problem with the containers.

Here is the codesandbox where I've tried to reproduce the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/heuristic-resonance-18bu96?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FNavigation%2FNavigation.css.ts

Here is a video with the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7MacY2maC4